# Can't connect to python socket server on a different network

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

I made this basic Python 3 socket server in an attempt to learn socket programming. I can connect to it using 'telnet 192.168.x.x 9001' on the same computer, running Ubuntu 16.04, but when I try using my other computer on a different network, Windows 10, on a different network it wont let me connect (when using the computer running Windows 10, I run the serve on Ubuntu).

This is the code I have written.

```
import socket
from _thread import start_new_thread

host = ""
port = 9001

class Server:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            self.server.bind((host, port))
        except socket.error as e:
            print(str(e))
        self.server.listen(10)

    def main(self, conn):
        while True:
            conn.send(str.encode("Enter some text to make uppercase: "))
            message = conn.recv(4096)
            message = str(message,'utf-8')
            conn.send(str.encode(message.upper()))

    def run(self):
        while True:
            conn, addr = self.server.accept()
            print("Connection from {}:{:d}".format(addr[0], addr[1]))
            start_new_thread(self.main, (conn, ))

my_server = Server(host, port)
my_server.run()
```

Comment: If you can connect to it from same machine using LAN IP address, then it is not a problem with your code. I can also see that you are binding to all interfaces. I'd guess firewall, or some other network based issue.

Comment: @SuperSaiyan can you think of anything I could try to fix this issue?

Comment: Not without knowing your network config. This may be even out of scope of stackoverflow. You will have better luck in one of the sister websites like super user.

Comment: @SuperSaiyan thanks for the help, I'll try find a site I can post this. Thankyou.